# How to retrieve variables in php sent by axios post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vue.js, axios

I want to send a POST request to a PHP script. I am using Axios:

```
axios.post('inc/vote.php', {
    id: this.selected,
}) .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

In the PHP file I am trying something like this to retrieve that id variable from axios:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

But seems it is not doing anything.

What is the correct way to retrieve variables from the request?

Comment: `$id` is empty or returns undefined variable `id`?

Comment: Use `$_POST['id'];`.  you forgot one `'`.  What you can do also is `var_dump($_POST);` to see if your $_POST contains the parameters you expect to receive.

Comment: This is a duplicate. It's not related to the OP's initial typo (already fixed). Axios is _not_ sending URL encoded requests by default, and so $_POST will not be populated. See the documentation and original post.

Comment: @Akintunde007 it is showing  Undefined index: id

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Axios sends data as a `JSON` inside request body not as a Form Data. So you can't access the post data using `$_POST['id']`.

**Frontend Solution**

To be able to access data using `$_POST['id']` you have to use FormData as the following:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('id', this.selected);
axios.post('inc/vote.php', {
    form
  }) .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

**Backend Solution**
if you are interested in getting the request body as associative array you can use:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$id = $data['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, man ! This worked for me like a charm.

Comment: You saved my job, thanks

Comment: unfortunatly not working on my side. I tested the form: it contains the entry. Once sent however the `$data['id']` is NULL