# PHP file does not receive variable from axios post

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue and for this project, I was trying to pass variable customer name value to PHP file where it will search the customer name. I am able to pass the value from axios.post following this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070403/how-to-retrieve-variables-in-php-sent-by-axios-post-request) , still my PHP file does not receive or print out the value.

Is there a way to pass value from axios.post and receive/print out in PHP file?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="customerName" placeholder="Enter customer first name">
  <button type="button" @click="buttonClicked()">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Method**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    customrName : '',
  },
  methods: {
    buttonClicked(){
      
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('customerName', this.customerName);

      axios.post(url,{
        form
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**PHP file**

```
header("Content-type: application/json";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
$CustomerName = $data['customer_name'];
echo $CustomerName;  /** does not print out the customer name typed from VIEW input field **/
```

Comment: You're adding the data as `customerName` in your FormData object in JS but are trying to retrieve it as `customer_name` in PHP. Those are two completely different names/keys.

Comment: You also have a typo in your Vue component. Your data object contains a `customrName` property instead of `customerName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four problems.

## The data format you are sending

You're POSTing a `FormData` object. That will generate a multipart request and not a JSON request.

Read the data from `$_POST`. Stay away from `php://input`.

## The name of your field

You send `customerName` and try to read `customer_name`. Pick one and stick with it.

## The content-type you respond with

You said `header("Content-type: application/json";` but you are outputting the user input raw. This is `text/plain` and not `application/json`.

Either use the right content-type or encode the output as JSON.

## You also made a typo.

The `)` is missing from the call to `header`.